# Using service containers in Azure DevOps pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to use service containers within Azure DevOps pipelines

The agent is an ubuntu host

I would like to have the agent run a powershell container and a playwright container

The doc for this is not very verbose

So far I have this in my main 'azure-pipelines.yml'

```
trigger: none
pr: none

resources:
  containers:
    - container: playwright
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.29.0-focal
    - container: pwsh
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell

pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

services:
  playwright: playwright
  pwsh: pwsh

stages:
  - stage: dev
    displayName: dev
    jobs:
      - template: templates/test.yml
```

And this in my 'template/test.yml' file

```
- job: run_tests
  displayName: Test
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "This is powershell"
      target:
        container: pwsh
    - script: yarn test:integration:ci
      displayName: "Run tests"
      env:
        environment: dev
        CI: true
      target:
        container: playwright
```

Azure pipelines does not like this. It is failing with:

```
/.azure/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 18, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'stages'
```

when I try to run the pipeline. I thought **stages:** was the first part of a pipeline? (but I am very new to Azure pipelines so my understanding might be way off)

Could anyone help to clarify why/where I am screwing up at all please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes to your yaml files.

`azure-pipelines.yml`

```
trigger: none
pr: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  

resources:
  containers:
  - container: playwright
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.29.0-focal
  - container: pwsh
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell


stages:
- stage: dev
  displayName: dev
  jobs:
  - template: templates/test.yml
```

`template.yml`

```
jobs:
- job: run_tests
  displayName: Test

  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest

  services:
    playwright: playwright
    pwsh: pwsh

  steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "This is powershell"
      target:
        container: pwsh
    - script: yarn test:integration:ci
      displayName: "Run tests"
      env:
        environment: dev
        CI: true
      target:
        container: playwright
```

Reason why you were getting the error (`/.azure/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 18, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'stages'`) is because of the property `services`. According to the example in [service containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#single-container-job) documentation, the property `services` is defined in the root level of the `yaml` because the example did not use any `stage` or `jobs`.

Since you are using `stages` and `jobs` in your yaml pipeline, the services property should be nested within your `job`.

Hence, I have moved the `services` to the `template.yml` file. You can check which property is allowed under a stage or job using this [YAML schema documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops)

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job-container?view=azure-pipelines